# Python 3: Como entender essa string

Tags: python, string

Estou com uma dúvida, sou iniciante e estou lendo o livro "Introdução a Programação com Python" 3° Edição. E me deparei com esse código abaixo.

## Programa 4.3 - Cálculo do Imposto de Renda

```
salario = float(input('Digite o salário para cálculo do imposto.: '))
base = salario
imposto = 0

if base > 3000:
    imposto = imposto + ((base - 3000) * 0.35)
    base = 3000
if base > 1000:
    imposto = imposto + ((base - 1000) * 0.20)

print(f'Salário: R${salario:6.2f} Imposto a pagar: R${imposto:6.2f}')
```

Está funcionando porém nesse 'print' não entendi "6.2f" sendo se eu retirar ele vai funcionar do mesmo jeito como no exemplo abaixo.

## Programa 4.3 - Cálculo do Imposto de Renda

```
salario = float(input('Digite o salário para cálculo do imposto.: '))
base = salario
imposto = 0

if base > 3000:
    imposto = imposto + ((base - 3000) * 0.35)
    base = 3000
if base > 1000:
    imposto = imposto + ((base - 1000) * 0.20)

print(f'Salário: R${salario} Imposto a pagar: R${imposto}')
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada em "Formatted string literals" no manual: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Isso são formatações de string - o link acima explica as opções usadas com o método 'format', que funcionam da mesma forma para as f-strings.  Depois da expressão, dentro de um par de chaves em uma "f-string", você pode usar os caractéres "!", ":" ou "=" (Python 3.8) para especificar como o resultado da expressão vai ser mostrado. No caso ":6.2f" significa: "formatar o número como um decimal com 6 digitos, sendo 2 depois do ponto decimal". Por padrão, a saída é alinhada  a direita, preenchendo os dígitos que sobrarem com espaços".

Answer (score 7):

Boa tarde Francisco, tudo bom?

Francisco, sobre o ':6.2f' é o seguinte:

Isto corresponde a uma formatação de saída no Python chamada Strings Literais Formatadas ou f-strings, como também são conhecidas.

**SOBRE O ':6'**    :
O número 6 após ':' lhe ajuda a definir o tamanho mínimo deste campo, impondo um número mínimo de caracteres, que basicamente servirá para ajustar a largura do campo. Caso o campo não tenha no mínimo 6 caracteres, o Python ajusta pra você, e a largura do campo ficará com no mínimo 6 caracteres.
Se Você testar no seu código e alterar este número por 10 verá que o espaço entre o 'R$' e o resultado fica maior. Faça testes, troque o 6 por 100 e verá que o tamanho só aumenta. O número inteiro após os ':', que no seu script é 6, serve para isso.

**SOBRE O '.2f'**       :
O .2f serve para controlar as casas decimais, ou seja, após a vírgula, que no caso do Python é um ponto '.' e não vírgula, você terá dois números. Apenas para exemplo, se o resultado for R$ 2500.00, o .2f trabalhou para fazer com que após o ponto você tivesse duas casas decimais, como no exemplo os 00. Faça testes, troque o 2 por 10 e verá que o número de casas decimais irá aumentar.

Sobre este tipo de formatação a documentação do Python possui algumas coisas bem interessantes, vou deixar um link que pode ajudar.

https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings

Espero ter ajudado. Boa sorte Francisco.